# AOSP 4.2.2: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

Tags: android, eclipse, swt, android-source

I am having problems running any AOSP commands after building. After `make`ing the source I do the following:

```
$ lunch full-eng
$ android
```

What happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:330)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:318)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:118)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:101)
```

I can't seem to find any solution to this. I am attempting to build [AOSP 4.2.2_r1.2b](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2b). I have built 4.0.4 before and not had this problem. I am running this version of java:

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here is the command that the `android` bash file (`/media/android/source/sdk/sdkmanager/app/etc/android`) generates:

```
java \
    -Xmx256M \
    -classpath /media/android/source/out/host/linux-x86/framework/sdkmanager.jar:/media/android/source/out/host/linux-x86/framework/swtmenubar.jar:/media/android/source/prebuilts/tools/linux-x86_64/swt/swt.jar \
    -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=/media/android/source/out/host/linux-x86/bin \
    com.android.sdkmanager.Main
```

Note how it still selects the 64 bit version of SWT.

I am aware of [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=43481). However, I have attempted solution 1 and it does not work. The other fixes appear too deep rooted for a new AOSP download and build...

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Try Running on JAVA 1.7 and add VM argument -d32

Comment: @AnkitSomani I already tried this, however, adding `-d32` allows me to access to only access the `android` program, but I am unable to specify any commands, such as `avd`. Additionally, modifying the bash file to add `-d32` to the command doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. I edit the command to:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/
```

And on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit try:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```